# Wrong http method in ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, nginx, http-method

In my rails app I need to send data from client to server via json request, method: POST. But client sends data with GET method.

server: nginx

client:

```
   $.ajax({
      url: "http://myurl",
      type: "POST",
      data: mydata,
      dataType: "script"
    });
```

In browser console I can see:

```
Request URL:    http://myurl?my_data
Request Method: GET
Status Code:    HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Nginx config:

```
upstream appname {
  server unix:///tmp/appname.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name app_url; 
  root /var/www/appname/current/public; 
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://appname; 
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  location ~* ^/assets/ {
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's just no good, but try altering the order of your params in the ajax call like this: type, datatype, url, data

Comment: That URL looks different too, are you sure there aren't any other ajax call on some even on this element?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your current method doesn't work. But you can try this

```
$.post( "http://myurl", mydata );
```

Comment: tried, still doesn't work. I suppose that there could be some problems with server settings